# web scraping in python: trying to get coordinates from a url given in a img using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to obtain the coordinates within a URL given in two links separated in the same line. Actually, I started to crawl all the URL and then the coordinates, but, maybe could be easier to get directly the coordinates. I'm using beautifulSoup and I have the next HTML code.

[image]

As you see, the url is given in the 'div class' followed by an 'id', then an img srcset and finally an src, if you realize, the <img src=> and the  have the URL where inside of each URL contain the coordinates (19.3410346%2C-99.1579533). I don't know and I haven't understood how can I get it.

I'm using bs4 and python 3.9

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

url='https://departamento.metroscubicos.com/MLM-912728287-departamento-en-zona-privilegiada-en-coyoacan-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=0264c9e9-5bf3-4964-bc39-b7b3609c4a7a' 
resp=requests.get(url) 
soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
```

Comment: please post the code, not an image. and the url you are scraping along with the code you've tried. thank you.

Comment: Please include your python code as well as the html as html (not image). And the source url. Are you using requests? Selenium? ......

Comment: thank you, the website is: 
https://departamento.metroscubicos.com/MLM-912728287-departamento-en-zona-privilegiada-en-coyoacan-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=0264c9e9-5bf3-4964-bc39-b7b3609c4a7a
I was using the library BeautifulSoup:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://departamento.metroscubicos.com/MLM-912728287-departamento-en-zona-privilegiada-en-coyoacan-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=0264c9e9-5bf3-4964-bc39-b7b3609c4a7a'
resp=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")

Answer (score 0):

They are present within a script tag. I would simply regex them out of the response text

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://departamento.metroscubicos.com/MLM-912728287-departamento-en-zona-privilegiada-en-coyoacan-_JM#position=1&search_layout=grid&type=item&tracking_id=0264c9e9-5bf3-4964-bc39-b7b3609c4a7a')

print('latitude = ', re.search(r'latitude: (.*?),',r.text).group(1))
print('longitude = ', re.search(r'longitude: (.*?),', r.text).group(1))
```